# Need guidance understanding head first C# interfaces

Tags: c#

I'd like some help understanding interface basics. Could someone please tell me if my comments below are accurate, and explain things further?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Creating a new ScaryScary object. The value of FunnyFunny's funnyThingIHave is now "big 
            //shoes". The value of ScaryScary's numberOfScaryThings is 14.
            ScaryScary fingersTheClown = new ScaryScary("big shoes", 14);

            //Creating a new reference called someFunnyClown and pointing it to the ScaryScary 
            //object? We still have the fingersTheClown object's values in place. How can we still 
            //use ScaryScary object's values if we are upcasting to FunnyFunny?
            FunnyFunny someFunnyClown = fingersTheClown;

            //Downcasting back to ScaryScary object (same as creating a new ScaryScary object)? 
            //We can use IScaryClown interface reference because ScaryScary implements IScaryClown. 
            //Why we first made a ScaryScary object, then cast it to FunnyFunny object, and then cast 
            //back to ScaryScary object?
            IScaryClown someOtherScaryClown = someFunnyClown as ScaryScary;

            //Is this the FunnyFunny's Honk() method? Does someOtherScaryClown now have both 
            //ScaryScary properties and methods and FunnyFunny's properties and methods?
            someOtherScaryClown.Honk();

            //Now calling the someOtherScaryClown(which is both ScaryScary and FunnyFunny object at 
            //the same time?) ScaryThingIHave method.
            Console.WriteLine(someOtherScaryClown.ScaryThingIHave);

            //Calling the someOtherScaryClown ScareLittleChildren() method.
            //My question is why we need the second and third steps. Couldn't we get the same thing 
            //done with just the ScaryScary fingersTheClown = new ScaryScary("big shoes", 14) line?
            someOtherScaryClown.ScareLittleChildren();                      
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

class FunnyFunny : IClown
    {
        public FunnyFunny(string funnyThingIHave)
        {
            this.funnyThingIHave = funnyThingIHave;
        }
        protected string funnyThingIHave;
        public string FunnyThingIHave
        {
            get { return "Hi kids! I have " + funnyThingIHave; }
        }
        public void Honk()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.FunnyThingIHave);
        }
    }

class ScaryScary : FunnyFunny, IScaryClown
    {
        public ScaryScary(string funnyThingIHave,
                          int numberOfScaryThings)
            : base(funnyThingIHave)
        {
            this.numberOfScaryThings = numberOfScaryThings;
        }
        private int numberOfScaryThings;
        public string ScaryThingIHave
        {
            get { return "I have " + numberOfScaryThings + " spiders"; }
        }
        public void ScareLittleChildren()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You can’t have my "
                             + base.funnyThingIHave);
        }
    }

interface IClown
    {
        string FunnyThingIHave { get; }
        void Honk();
    }

interface IScaryClown : IClown
    {
        string ScaryThingIHave { get; }
        void ScareLittleChildren();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code and implementation looks fine, you can insert a ***break point*** and run in debug mode and navigate using ***Step into in Visual studio***, that will help you understand the flow

*Here's the notes that I had maintain to understand interfaces better. Hope this would help clarify things*

#### *What ?*

Interfaces are basically a contract that all the classes *implementing* the Interface should follow. They looks like a class but has no implementation.

In `C#` Interface names by convention is defined by Prefixing an 'I' so if you want to have an interface called shapes, you would declare it as `IShapes`

#### *Now Why ?*

#### **`Improves code re-usability`**

Lets say you want to draw `Circle`, `Triangle.`  
You can group them together and call them `Shapes`and have methods to draw `Circle` and `Triangle`
But having concrete implementation would be a bad idea because tomorrow you might decide to have 2 more `Shapes` `Rectangle` & `Square`. Now when you add them there is a great chance that you might break other parts of your code.

*With Interface you isolate the different implementation from the Contract*

---

*Live Scenario Day 1*

You were asked to create an App to Draw Circle and Triangle

```
interface IShapes
{
   void DrawShape();
   
 }

class Circle : IShapes
{
    
    public void DrawShape()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Implementation to Draw a Circle");
    }
}

Class Triangle: IShapes
{
     public void DrawShape()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Implementation to draw a Triangle");
    }
}
```

```
static void Main()
{
     List <IShapes> shapes = new List<IShapes>();
        shapes.Add(new Circle());
        shapes.Add(new Triangle());

        foreach(var shape in shapes)
        {
            shape.DrawShape();
        }
}
```

*Live Scenario Day 2*

If you were asked add `Square` and `Rectangle` to it, all you have to do is create the implentation for it in `class Square: IShapes` and in `Main` add to list `shapes.Add(new Square());`

Comment: Thanks for the great overview and example of interfaces. Also pointing out to use debugging was helpful!

Comment: you're welcome glad it helped, it will be nice if you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the green tickbox so it serves as a reference to others . Cheers !!